# Netbeans doesn't finish creating the project

Tags: php, windows, netbeans, ide

I'm trying to create a new project. But it won't finish creating the project. It stops at 29% and remains there indefinitely.
Steps I'm taking:
1. Choosing project type (php).
2. Choosing name and location (it's an existing project, also netbeans data goes into another folder)
I'm not copying the sources folder to another location.

IOS - Windows 8.1
Netbeans version - 8.0.2

**edit:** The project wasn't done previously in netbeans

Comment: I could suggest to reinstall netbeans...

Comment: If it's an existing project, why not 'Open Project...' rather than 'New Project...'? I mean you said even NetBeans (meta?)data is already put into a seperate folder. So I assume there already is a NetBeans project you are trying to open, correct?

Comment: See edit. By "netbeans data goes into another folder", I meant that I chose to put the data into a separate folder, not the project folder.

Comment: @Masiorama That was the first thing I did. Not a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may know, Netbeans projects have a folder/dir with name "nbproject".
Did your exiting project have "nbproject" Folder ?

Comment: No. It wasn't previously developed in netbeans.

Comment: Create a new project, set sources directory to the one you have with current files (might want to back up the files before if anything goes wrong).

Comment: Ok, I tried with 2 different projects. It works, first one was created in 5 minutes, the second in about 20 minutes. Is it supposed to take that long?

Comment: I don't tried it so long, But May be it depend On the size of your project. lets other friends help you about it.

Comment: Hmmm. Seems to be working, but taking a long time to create it.